# sample of neural network

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network

In the neural network code that I've written, I could not get an answer since the problem of alignment.

I wrote a neural network code (based on some other). I tried to build input and output in the right way. While I defined the class and operations correctly, I could not get an answer since the problem of alignment. Error : shapes (127,3) and (1,4) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

`Datafile = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\Hasan\Desktop\ANN\x.xlsx")` is  127x3

`Target = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\Hasan\Desktop\ANN\y.xlsx")` is 127x1

`class Neural_Network(object):`

```
def __init__(self):
  self.inputlayer = 1

  self.w1 = np.random.randn(self.inputlayer, self.hiddenlayer)

  self.z = np.dot(Datafile, self.w1)
```

I think it's because of the dimension of two matrices but even, when I changed the dimensions it did not work. 
All help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For matrix multiplication `(dot product)`, number of `columns of first matrix` should be equal to number of `rows of second matrix`.

In your case, `Datafile` has `3 columns` while `w1` has `1 row`, that's why it's giving you error because of incorrect dimensions.

For giving you example, I am assuming random matrices,

```
Datafile = np.random.rand(127, 3)
w1 = np.random.rand(3, 127)

z = np.dot(Datafile, w1)

print(z.shape)
```

Output: `(127, 127)`

In this example, `Datafile` has 3 columns and `w1` has 3 rows so in this case, `dot-product` will be successful.